# How to disable the option of a kubernetes node in cordon mode?

Tags: kubernetes

I ran the command `kubectl cordon <nameNode>` and now I don't know how to make my node schedulable again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kubectl uncordon <node name>
```

try above command